# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, max-pooling

I'm trying to solve classification problem. I don't know why I'm getting this error:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]`

**This is the main code:**

```
model = createModel()
filesPath=getFilesPathWithoutSeizure(i, indexPat)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75)##problem here
def createModel():
    input_shape=(1,11, 3840)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), strides=( 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_first", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=( 2, 2),data_format= "channels_first",  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #C2
    model.add(Conv2D(32, ( 3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    #c3
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=( 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_first",  activation='relu'))#incertezza se togliere padding
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format= "channels_first", padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    opt_adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

**Error:**

```
    history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), #end=75),#It take the first 75%
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1815, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:975 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
    /home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:191 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_9 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]
```

Comment: What line of code triggered that exception? Is this line somewhere in your provided code?

Comment: Can you maybe put full exception? It has no beginning part (first lines are skipped). Hence we can't see what line of code triggered exception.

Comment: What is the shape of your numpy arrays generated by function `generate_arrays_for_training()`?

Comment: @Arty yes , this is the line `history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75)##problem here` , shape of numpy array generated by `generate_arrays_for_training()` (1,11,3840)

Comment: @Edaildiz I understood the reason, I'll write an answer now.

Comment: @Arty thanks a lot for your help , waiting for the solution .

Comment: Done! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64138518/941531) is the answer.

Comment: Basically if you're training on data with batches of size 1 you should expand dims there. If your training data `X` is of numpy shape `(1, 11, 3840)` then you have to do `X = np.expand_dims(X, 0)` with [this function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Comment: If your images for all layers should be 3-dimensional, with 1 channel then you have to expand dims of your generated training data, do `X = np.expand_dims(X, 0)` using [this function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) so that your training X data is of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)`, e.g. batch with 1 object, only then you can have `input_shape = (1, 11, 3840)`.

Comment: Also I see that you're writing everywhere `data_format= "channels_first"`, by default all functions are `channels_last`, in order not to write this everywhere you can reshape your generated by `generate_arrays_for_training()` data just once, if it is `X` of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)` then you do `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)`. And you channels will become last dimension.

Comment: Also feel free to ask extra questions if something still not working.

Comment: @Arty Thanks a lot for helping me . I don't understand why i should use  `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)` ??

Comment: It was just a suggestion how to beautify your code, after transposing you don't need to write `"channels_first"` param everywhere, but if you don't want to change code then don't do any transposing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras actually always hides `0-th` dimension, also known as `batch` dimension. Everywhere where you put `input_shape = (A, B, C)` actually batch dimension should not be mentioned there, `(A, B, C)` should be a shape of one object (or image in your case). For example if you say `input_shape = (1,11, 3840)` then it actually means that data for training or prediction should be a numpy array of shape something like `(7, 1,11, 3840)`, i.e. training has `7` objects in the batch. So this `7` is size of batch, number of objects to train in parallel.

So if your one object (e.g. image) is of shape `(11, 3840)` then you have to write `input_shape = (11, 3840)` everywhere, without mentioning batch size.

Why is Keras hiding `0-th` batch dimension? Because keras is expecting different size of batch, today you may provide 7 objects, tomorrow 9 and same network will work for both. But shape of one object which is `(11, 3840)` should never change and provided data for training generated by function `generate_arrays_for_training()` should be always of size `(BatchSize, 11, 3840)`, where `BatchSize` can vary, you may generate batch of `1` or `7` or `9` objects-images each of shape `(11, 3840)`.

If your images for all layers should be 3-dimensional, with 1 channel then you have to expand dims of your generated training data, do `X = np.expand_dims(X, 0)` using [this function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) so that your training X data is of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)`, e.g. batch with 1 object, only then you can have `input_shape = (1, 11, 3840)`.

Also I see that you're writing everywhere `data_format= "channels_first"`, by default all functions are `channels_last`, in order not to write this everywhere you can reshape your generated by `generate_arrays_for_training()` data just once, if it is `X` of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)` then you do `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)`. And you channels will become last dimension.

Transposing moves one dimension to another place. But for your case as you have just `1` channel than instead of transposing you can just reshape e.g. `X` of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)` can be reshaped by `X = X.reshape(1, 11, 3840, 1)` and it will become of shape `(1, 11, 3840, 1)`. This is only needed if you want not to write `"channels_first"` everywhere, but if you don't want to beautify your code than transposing/reshaping is not needed at all!

As I remember from my past Keras somehow doesn't like dimensions of size 1, it basically tries to remove them in several different functions, i.e. if keras sees array of shape `(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4)` it almost always tries to reshape it to be `(2, 3, 4)`. Thus `np.expand_dims()` gets actually ignored. Probably the only solution in that case would be to generate batch of size 2 images at least.

You may also read my [long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101952/941531), although it is a bit unrelated, it may help you to understand how training/prediction in Keras works, especially you may read last paragraphs, numbered `1-12`.

**Update**: As appeared to be the problem was solved due to help of next modifications:

1. In data generating function it was needed to do expanding dims twice, i.e. `X = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(X, 0), 0)`.
2. In data generating function another was needed `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)`.
3. In code of network input shape set to be `input_shape = (11, 3840, 1)`.
4. In code of network all substrings `data_format = "channels_first"` were removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. But i don't understand why should i do `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)` ??

Comment: @Edayildiz Transposing moves one dimension to another place. But yes for your case as you have just 1 channel than instead of transposing you can just reshape e.g. `X` of shape `(1, 1, 11, 3840)` can be reshaped by `X = X.reshape(1, 11, 3840, 1)` and it will become of shape `(1, 11, 3840, 1)`. This all is needed if you want not to write `"channels_first"`, but if you don't want to beautify your code than transposing/reshaping is not needed at all!

Comment: very well , so if I write "channels_last" then my input shape should be `input_shape=(1,11,3840,1)` ??

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error after editing my code by expanding the dimension

Comment: @Edayildiz I think it could be the case, at least as I remembered from my past that Keras incorrectly handles batch of size 1, it just removes always dimensions with size 1. The only possible solution for you is to generate at least batch of size 2, please generate numpy array for training of size `(2, 1, 11, 3840)`.

Comment: @Edayildiz If batch of size 2 doesn't help tell me I'll continue with other suggestions, I have more ideas. We'll fix this issue finally.

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_46 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 2, 16, 6, 3840]` when i write `input_shape=(2,1,11,3840)`

Comment: @Edayildiz Just write `input_shape=(1,11,3840)`, you need not to put `2` (batch size) in `input_shape`, in Keras you should never specify size of batch in `input_shape`, just remove `2` from there and it should help.

Comment: @Edayildiz If your training data generator creates numpy arrays of size `(2,1,11,3840)` then in your code for param `input_shape` you need to write `input_shape=(1,11,3840)`, you should always omit batch size (`2`) in your `input_shape` param.

Comment: I get the error in the post `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_28 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, None]`

Comment: @Edayildiz This error happens with batch of 2 images? Then try to do next thing for generated array `X`, if it is of shape `(2, 1, 11, 3840)` then first try to transpose like I said `X = X.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)`. If it doesn't help I have another solution. BTW, I'll try moving this comments discussion to chat.

Comment: How to write `(2,1,11,3840)` in input_shape and you said i can't write the batch size in keras ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222315/discussion-between-arty-and-edayildiz).

Comment: @Edayildiz Lets have a discussion in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222315/discussion-between-arty-and-edayildiz) .