# Input error concatenating two CNN branches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a 3D facial recognition algorithm using CNNs with multiple classes. I have an image generator for rgb images, and an image generator for depth images (grayscale). As I have two distinct inputs, I made two different CNN models, one with shape=(height, width, 3) and another with shape=(height, width, 1). Independently I can fit the models with its respective image generator, but after concatenating the two branches and merging both image generators, I got this warning and error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 400, 400, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 400, 400,
> 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='Depth_Input_input'),
> name='Depth_Input_input', description="created by layer
> 'Depth_Input_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible
> shape (None, None)
>
> "ValueError: Input 0 of layer Depth_Input is incompatible with the
> layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received:
> (None, None)"

What can i do to solve this? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
height=400
width=400
shape=(height,width)

    # ########################### RGB ############################
model_rgb = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', name="RGB_Input", input_shape=(height,width, 3)))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model_rgb.add(Dropout(0.3))

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
#model_rgb.add(Dropout(0.2))

model_rgb.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
#model_rgb.add(Dropout(0.2))

model_rgb.add(Flatten())
model_rgb.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_rgb.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model_rgb.add(Dropout(0.3))

# ########################### DEPTH ###########################
model_depth = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', name="Depth_Input", input_shape=(height, width, 1)))
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model_depth.add(Dropout(0.3))
                   
model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))                      
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))                      
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))                      
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))                
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_depth.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))                      
model_depth.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model_depth.add(Flatten())
model_depth.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model_depth.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_depth.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model_depth.add(Dropout(0.3))

#### Concatenating branches ####

merge = Concatenate()([model_rgb.output, model_depth.output])
merged_out = Dense(units=16, activation='relu')(merge)
merged_out = Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')(merged_out)

merged_model = Model([model_rgb.input, model_depth.input], merged_out) 

merged_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history_merged = merged_model.fit(gen_flow,
                                  epochs=70,
                                  shuffle=True,
                                  )
```

Here is the code for the generators:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                    rotation_range=20, 
                                    width_shift_range=0.4, 
                                    height_shift_range=0.4, 
                                    shear_range=0.4, 
                                    zoom_range=0.4, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# ########################### RGB ###########################
print("RGB Generators: \n")
train_generator_rgb = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_data_rgb, target_size=shape,
                                                        class_mode='categorical', 
                                                        batch_size=16)

val_generator_rgb = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=val_data_rgb, 
                                                    target_size=shape,
                                                    class_mode='categorical', 
                                                    batch_size=12)
# ########################### --- ###########################

# ########################### DEPTH ###########################
print("\n\nDepth Generators: \n")
train_generator_depth = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_data_depth, 
                                                          target_size=shape, 
                                                          color_mode="grayscale",
                                                          class_mode='categorical', 
                                                          batch_size=16)

val_generator_depth = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=val_data_depth, 
                                                      target_size=shape, 
                                                      color_mode="grayscale",
                                                      class_mode='categorical', 
                                                      batch_size=12)
# ########################### ----- ###########################

def gen_flow_for_two_inputs(X1, X2):
    
    while True:
            X1i = train_generator_rgb.next()
            X2i = train_generator_depth.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]

# Create generator
gen_flow = gen_flow_for_two_inputs(train_data_rgb, train_data_depth)
```

Plotted model of the merged branches:
[image: merged_model]

Comment: It looks like your input layer expects an input tensor with shape (None, 400, 400, 1) as you intended but is actually receiving (None, None). I would check to see that your data generators are in fact generating the images you expect them to (plot the input before the first layer). There might be a problem with the paths or even the images themselves.

Comment: I dont think its because of the images or paths themselves, because I was able to fit each model with its individual generator and it trained fine. The error may have arisen from the combination of the two generators, which I am not sure if it is correctly implemented..

Comment: It's odd that this worked before. Can you think of anything else you may have added in the process? Another thing I can think of is the `target_size=shape` parameter. You declared the same one `shape = (height, width)` for both the depth and RGB inputs, but the RGB input should also have a channel input. This would explain the error you're getting. TF can handle the batch dimension but the rest should fit. See this post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138041/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-9-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expe

Comment: @OphirS No, I didn't changed anything else. Yes but that was on the generator, it only accepts a tuple, but on the first layer of each CNN model, I specified the channels in addition to the image's size. Thanks for the post, I will have a look :)

Comment: Please post what you find, I'm curious to know what it was :)

Comment: @OphirS I just solved it! The problem was with the union of the generators in the function gen_flow_for_two_inputs(X1, X2). The correct form is yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1] instead of yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]

Comment: Good job! Those look the same to me. Did you mean `yield [X1i[0], X2i[0], X1i[1]]` instead of `yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]` ?

Comment: @OphirS Yes! Exactly that. Thanks for the support you gave :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments

> The problem was with the union of the generators in the function
> `gen_flow_for_two_inputs(X1, X2)`. The correct form is `yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]` instead of `yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]` (paraphrased from sergio_baixo)

Working code for the generators

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                    rotation_range=20, 
                                    width_shift_range=0.4, 
                                    height_shift_range=0.4, 
                                    shear_range=0.4, 
                                    zoom_range=0.4, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,
                                    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# ########################### RGB ###########################
print("RGB Generators: \n")
train_generator_rgb = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_data_rgb, target_size=shape,
                                                        class_mode='categorical', 
                                                        batch_size=16)

val_generator_rgb = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=val_data_rgb, 
                                                    target_size=shape,
                                                    class_mode='categorical', 
                                                    batch_size=12)
# ########################### --- ###########################

# ########################### DEPTH ###########################
print("\n\nDepth Generators: \n")
train_generator_depth = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_data_depth, 
                                                          target_size=shape, 
                                                          color_mode="grayscale",
                                                          class_mode='categorical', 
                                                          batch_size=16)

val_generator_depth = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=val_data_depth, 
                                                      target_size=shape, 
                                                      color_mode="grayscale",
                                                      class_mode='categorical', 
                                                      batch_size=12)
# ########################### ----- ###########################

def gen_flow_for_two_inputs(X1, X2):
    
    while True:
            X1i = train_generator_rgb.next()
            X2i = train_generator_depth.next()
            yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]

# Create generator
gen_flow = gen_flow_for_two_inputs(train_data_rgb, train_data_depth)
```